# Overlay a div inside a list item

Tags: html, css, css-position, ionic-framework

I'm trying to implement auto-complete inside a form item, where as the user types it creates a dropdown menu with a list of suggestions, which are clickable. This is done inside the [Ionic Framework](http://ionicframework.com).

I've made a codepen to demonstrate what I want. (look at the auto-complete field, and the grey hidden box below it)

http://codepen.io/pbernasconi/pen/Cgobi

My dropdown:

```
<div class="list">
  <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
    <span class="input-label">License #</span>
    <input type="text" placeholder="AUTO COMPLETE FIELD">
    <div class="input-dropdown">
      <ul class="input-dropdown-menu">
        <li>...</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </label>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
.input-dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    background: grey;
    border: solid 1px #000;
    z-index: 1001;
    overflow: visible;
}

.input-dropdown-menu {
}
```

This issue is that `position: absolute` doesn't allow me to overlay over the list item below the auto-complete field, as you can see in the codepen.

[Here's an example of a solution](http://jsfiddle.net/Matt_Coughlin/C4Qy2/1/), which for some reason doesn't work for me.

Does anyone know how to implement this dropdown to overlay over it's parent's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The label item overflow is hidden and the dropdown list is inside it, so you can't see it.

Comment: Thank you, didn't think it was that simple. I added `.item-autocomplete {
    position: static;
    overflow: visible;
}`

Answer (score 0):

```
// jquery code

$(document).ready(function() {
$("#test").focus(function(){
    $(".input-dropdown-menu").show();
});
$("#test").mouseleave(function(){
    $(".input-dropdown-menu").hide();
});
});


 //use css 

input-dropdown {
position: absolute;
background: grey;
border: solid 1px #000;
z-index: 1001;
overflow: visible;
margin-left:65px;
}

.input-dropdown-menu {
display:none;
}


 //use html


<div class="list">
<label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
<span class="input-label">License #</span>
<input type="text" placeholder="AUTO COMPLETE FIELD" id ="test">
<div class="input-dropdown">
  <ul class="input-dropdown-menu">
    <li>111</li>
    <li>111</li>
    <li>111</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```